# How i can know how many parameters are necessary in a method of another class? PHP

Tags: php

Example:

file: \bla\test1.php

```
class Test {

    public function Hello($one) {

    }
}
```

file: \bla2\test2.php

```
class World {

    public function GetNumberOfParameters($class, $method) {
       // output: number of parameters required of method Hello 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure (not well documented) but have a look at [ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php) and [getNumberOfRequiredParameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofrequiredparameters.php). (The comments might be helping.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection to get the number of parameters. Something like:

```
$reflec = new ReflectionClass('Test');
$helloMethod = $reflec->getMethod('Hello');
echo "Number of params is: ".$helloMethod->getNumberOfParameters();
```

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

I'd consider why you want to do this however. I can think of very few cases where this would be of any use.

Example: http://codepad.org/zWca7mFz

Comment: Thanks! But this solution don't work.. This gave me a error "class does not exist"

Comment: @user5011503 That means the class hasn't been loaded. Have you included or defined it? See this example http://codepad.org/zWca7mFz